# 2017 MacBook Pro 13" with Touchbar (USB-C) can't connect to LED Cinema Display 27" (Mini DisplayPort)

Tags: macbook-pro, cinema-display

I purchased a new 2017 MacBook Pro 13" w/ Touchbar (updated in June) from my local Apple Store. I want to connect my 2010 LED Cinema Display 27" which uses a Mini DisplayPort connection. The clerk at the Apple Store wrongfully sold me the Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter, which did not work. I later confirmed on Apple's support site that it does not work for this use.

I then purchased an AllSmartLife "USB C Type to Mini DisplayPort Adapter" from Amazon, which had many reviews from people having successfully made the connection I am trying to make. I received the adapter, plugged it in and... nothing. I looked back realized none of the reviews specified they had a 2017 MBP.

Does anyone have this exact setup with a successful connection? If so, which adapters did you use?

Comment: I have the same question, when I plugged the adapter to the DELL U2715H, it's working. But, on LED Cinema Display 27， there is noting! WTF?!

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem and after much search, came to this solution:

1. Dual-Link DIV to DisplayPort using Apple's connector
2. [DisplayPort to USB-C using this connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079CBNK8M) Which is a  USB-C to Mini-DisplayPort and Charging Port Adapter {Amazon.com}

Keep in mind that the Cinema display also needs a USB-A connection (I'm guessing to provide power to some internal circuit for link negotiation?), so you'll need a separate adapter from USB-C to USB-A.

I'm also an amateur photographer and shoots with a Canon 5DsR, editing my photos using an AdobeRGB LG 4K display (10-bit color to support AdobeRGB). I've also tested the DisplayPort adapter on this display and it works flawlessly.

On a side note - reason why you'll need a separate adapter for USB-A instead of having the USB-A built-in to the DisplayPort adapter is that only way for USB-C to support DisplayPort data-rate is using Display Protocol, which turns a bi-directional USB connection (10Gbit/direction) to a uni-directional output port (20Gbit total). If you work out the math: 3840 * 2160 * 10-bit color per channel * 3 color channels (RGB) * 60 Hz = 15Gbit/s.